# how to create ref for Autocomplete component from react-native-autocomplete-input for make it focus?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

how to create ref with Autocomplete component react-native-autocomplete-input for focus function ?

so i have this code

```
<View 
           onTouchEndCapture={() => {this.inputCity.focus()}}>

                <Autocomplete
                    ref={inputCity => this.inputCity = inputCity}
                    
                />
            </View>
```

how to make autocomplete component focus when user trigger from view component?

Comment: [PR](https://github.com/mrlaessig/react-native-autocomplete-input/pull/220#pullrequestreview-850285986) is opened

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think instead of using View and onTouchEndCapture, use TouchableOpacity and onPress function may focus Autocomplete

```
<TouchableOpacity
   onPress={()=>this.inputCity.focus()}>
    <Autocomplete
      ref={inputCity => this.inputCity = inputCity}/>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: and also i need to add changes inside node modules to give a ref props in the library and i already PR to the git of the creator of react-native-autocomplete-input to add ref in the TextInput at library react-native-autocomplete-input